# SQL Server: "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to copy the results from a view to a table using:

```
insert into tableA 
  select * from viewB order by id;
```

I get the error message -

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

TableA and ViewB have about 80 fields. Trying to figure out which one's might have a type mismatch will take forever. How can I determine what column is causing the error quickly?

Comment: How many datetime columns are there in tableA? have a look at those

Comment: yes, agree - those kind of message "something went wrong" are pretty pointless..... have been wondering myself why the SQL Server team can't manage to at least tell us **WHAT** column caused this conversion to fail.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you a list of all columns in your `TableA` that have a date-related type (DATE, DATETIME, DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET etc.):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('TableA')
AND system_type_id IN (40, 42, 43, 58, 61)
ORDER BY name
```

You could run this on both tables and see if you find any discrepancies.

Or you could run this on both tables - it will give you a list of columns (names) and their associated datatype:

```
SELECT
    c.NAME,
    t.name  
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE object_id = object_id('TableA')
ORDER BY c.name
```

Maybe you'll see a column in TableB that's of type varchar that's being mapped to a column of type DATETIME in TableA and then find your culprit that way.

Marc

Comment: Using the top method limited it to around 20 columns I had to check. I eventually found it.

Looks like you could probably rewrite the bottom method so it would output the fields from the view and the table next to one another.

Comment: Your second query could be replaced by `EXEC sp_columns 'TableA'` and you will get the full column description.

Comment: yes, but then you're dealing with a stored proc output - not a nice table which you can select additional fields, order, and so on. I prefer the system catalog view over those built-in stored procs

Answer (score 2):

You have bad data in one of your fields. Check each of the fields that should contain dates with the isdate() function.

```
Select idfield, mydatefield from mytable where isdate(mydatefield) = 0
```

You will see the records which contain invalid dates. This is one reason why it is never a good idea to store dates as string data.

Answer (score 1):

They mostly DATETIME fields? Looks like it's trying to shove a string into a DATETIME so you can start by looking at the first few of those.

Shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

As a debug capability you might want to perform the select query from the view then push them down in a single insert into tableA.

Then it will throw an error containing which column couldn't be inserted.  Assuming you can do this manually.  Other than that, is there any way you can avoid having a string as your datetime column?